# Wordpress xml import too slow

Tags: import, xml

I'm trying to import posts and media with xml but is really slow, because there are 160000 posts and 160000 media.
Further many posts are duplicated (same title, different categories and obviously different id) but wordpress import only one of them, is there any other method?

Comment: Is that a WXR file? There are tools to split them into smaller sections, and you can use [wp cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/import/) to import them rather than the web interface, but even if you can rule out data transfer time by e.g. restoring all the posts to a local copy of the database and then copying the database and media to your site afterwards, you do still have a lot of posts.

Comment: I'm still doing it in local.
wp_cli is faster? Maybe I'll try it.
I was thinking about a mysql query to export only what I need but it's really hard.